Longhorn: Problem with setting tolerations and nodeSelector to engine-image and csi-plugin DaemonSet's
I have some problem. Before i deployed longhorn via helm chart , i edited tolerations and nodeSelector for longhorn-manager DS in values.yaml in order to divide longhorn-manager*, instance-manager* pods to specific nodes. But unfortunately it works only for those pods. Engine-image* and longhorn-csi-plugin* pods has been deployed to other nodes anyway. For correctly working longhorn-manager also needs engine-image* and longhorn-csi-plugin-* pods on the same nodes with longhorn-manager-* pods. Can i use the chart to specify tolerations and nodeSelector for engine-image* and longhorn-csi-plugin-* pods or how i can solve my problem by another way?
I tried to set taintToleration and systemManagedComponentsNodeSelector in defaultSettings section of values.yaml. But result same.
